# php, loop ( echo from 100 to 100), while

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a loop within my script and I need to echo "this is another 100" on each 100th time . For example at 147886900, 147886800, 147886700, 147886600 etc

```
$account_id_new = 147887000;
while($account_id_new > 2)
{
  //do something 
  // echo " this is 100th time";
  $account_id_new = $account_id_new-1;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `$account_id_new` is a multiple of 100 by doing this:

```
if ($account_id_new % 100 === 0) {
     echo "100 divides the account id evenly.\n";
}
```

For more information, see the article on the [modulo operator on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the modulus operator?

```
if ($account_id_new % 100 === 0)
{
    echo '100th time';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is the "do something" part of the code actually doing something? Otherwise, you may just want to decrement by 100 instead of by 1.

Otherwise, try the following

```
$account_id_new = 147887000;
while($account_id_new > 2) {
    if($account_id % 100 == 0)
       echo " this is 100th time";

$account_id_new = $account_id_new-1;
```

}